# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable // class?

Tags: python, class

Here is my `Transaction` class:

```
class Transaction(object):
    def __init__(self, company, price, date):
        self.company = company
        self.price = price
        self.date = date
    def company(self):
        return self.company
    def price(self):
        return self.price
    def date(self):
        self.date = datetime.strptime(self.date, "%y-%m-%d")
        return self.date
```

And when I'm trying to run the `date` function:

```
tr = Transaction('AAPL', 600, '2013-10-25')
print tr.date()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/Documents/folder/file.py", line 597, in <module>
    print tr.date()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You can not have an instance variable with the same name as a method, obviously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `self.date = date`, the `self.date` here actually hides the method `def date(self)`, so you should consider changing either the attribute or the method name.

```
print Transaction.date  # prints <unbound method Transaction.date>
tr = Transaction('AAPL', 600, '2013-10-25') #call to __init__ hides the method 
print tr.date           # prints 2013-10-25, hence the error.
```

**Fix:**

```
    def convert_date(self):  #method name changed
        self.date = datetime.strptime(self.date, "%Y-%m-%d") # It's 'Y' not 'y'
        return self.date

tr = Transaction('AAPL', 600, '2013-10-25')
print tr.convert_date()
```

**Output:**

```
2013-10-25 00:00:00
```

Comment: I was about to write this myself then I saw that you had already written it :P

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance variable (`self.date`) and a method `def date(self):` by the same name. Upon constructing the instance, the former overwrites the later.

Consider renaming your method (`def get_date(self):`) or using [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).